# Как изменить размер консоли Linux, C?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, консоль, ascii

Необходимо устанвовить определенный размер консольного окна по горизонтали и вертикали, а так же желательно (но уже не обязателно) разместить окно так, чтобы его верхний левый угол был точно в соответствующем углу экрана.

Как это сделать без использования сторонних бибилиотек, а лишь функциями предоставляемыми API Linux?

Comment: боюсь границу между linux api и сторонним провести будет не просто

Comment: Что такое: linux api и консольноне окно? Реч идет о псевдо терминале в GUI или что типо мультиплексора tmux/screen?

Comment: возможно правильней было бы сказать что мне надо даже не размер окна указать, а скорее размер буфера этого консольного окна. Короче говоря количество столбцов и строк.

Comment: Если речь о задании размера при запуске, то обычно это можно указать в аргументах командной строки (в exec()/system() если запускаете из своей программы). Например:  `xfce4-terminal --geometry=132x20`

Comment: может вам посмотреть в сторону ncurses?

Answer (score 0):

В файле */usr/include/termios.h* определена такая структура:

```
struct winsize {
        unsigned short ws_row;         // Количество строк
        unsigned short ws_col;         // Символов в строке
        unsigned short ws_xpixel;      // Размеры символов в пикселях,
        unsigned short ws_ypixel;      // насколько я знаю - не используются.
};
```

Получить её можно с помощью вызова *ioctl()* с командой TIOCGWINSZ. Установить новые значения - с помощью TIOCSWINSZ.

Если мой ответ оказался не очень понятным, то привожу пример программы, которая будучи запущена в окне терминала, выдаёт размер этого окна:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *arhv[]) {

    struct winsize ws;
    int rc;
    int fd = 0;

    rc = ioctl(fd, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
    if (rc < 0) {
        printf("Произошла ошибка!\n");
        perror("ioctl: ");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        printf("Ширина окна=%d, Высота окна=%d\n", ws.ws_col, ws.ws_row);
    }
}
```

Вот результаты её работы. Она выдала текущий размер окна. Я уменьшил окошко и опять запустил. Она выдала новый размер:

```
$ gcc main.c 
$ ./a.out 
Ширина окна=103, Высота окна=49
$ ./a.out 
Ширина окна=74, Высота окна=35
lary@dtk58:~/tmp$
```

Первый параметр вызова *ioctl* для данной конкретной команды TIOCGWINSZ не играет никакой роли. Поэтому я поставил == 0, так как знаю, что fd == 0 в моеём сеансе - точно есть.

Comment: и кому это делать? на stdout?

Comment: @PavelGridin Причём тут *stdout*?! Вопрос задан про консоль. У любого сеанса только одна консоль. Либо вообще - нет. А *stdout* можно и в файл назначить... и в */dev/null...*

Comment: По крайней мере `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal` не хочет менять размер по `ioctl(0, TIOCSWINSZ, &ws)` (ошибки нет, но размер не меняется, последующий `ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws)`  возвращает тот размер, что мы установили, но он не соответствует реальному. Снова реальный размер устанавливается, если изменить размер окна мышкой)

Comment: Многие терминалы не будут менять свой размер. Хотя какой-то простенький xterm  может послушаться.